# Invalid identifier error while running plsql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Since my school does not allow me to post the code, hence i had to come back home and put up an example to show the issue i am facing. My school asked me to do a homework on dynamic sql to create a table and later insert one dummy record to it. But while doing it I am facing the below issue. Please find the code below for your reference. Thank you.

### Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure table_creation(table_name in varchar2,col1  varchar2,col2 varchar2)
is
l_stat varchar2(3000);
v_stat varchar2(1000);
a varchar2(10):='1';
b varchar2(10):='Dummy';
begin
l_stat:='create table '||table_name||' ("'||col1||'"   varchar2(10),"'||col2||'" varchar2(10))';
execute immediate l_stat;
execute immediate 'insert into '||table_name||'('||col1||','||col2||')  values    (:x,:y)' using a,b;
end;
/
```

### Plsql Block to call the procedure:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
a varchar2(10);
b varchar2(10);
c varchar2(10);
begin
a:='Example';
b:='id';
c:='nm';
table_creation(a,b,c);
dbms_output.put_line('Yes');
end;
/
```

The procedure is getting created perfectly and while running the above block i am getting the below error .

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NM": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.TABLE_CREATION", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

But when I checked the created table. The table exists with 0 records. The structure of the table is as follows.

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 ID                                                 VARCHAR2(10)
 NM                                                 VARCHAR2(10)
```

Any help from your end is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible silly question, but did you make sure the table did not already exist?

Comment: The issue looks to be around the fact that you're double-quoting your columns in the create table statement, but in the insert statement, you're not. If you're going to use doublequotes in your create table statement (which enforces case sensitivity in the identifier names), then you're going to need to use doublequotes when referring to those columns elsewhere. So, either remove the doublequotes from your create table statement, or add them into your insert statement.

Comment: @johnHC if table already exists he would not have received this error message.

Comment: Are you sure about the requirement? It is **very** uncommon and poor design to create tables (or any other database object) with dynamic SQL. Typically dynamic SQL are mainly used for DML's (like INSERT) or queries.

Comment: Yes that is to make us understand what will happen if we use ddl statement inside a procedure.

Comment: @boneist thank you. Double quotes was the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick,

Please note that the above procedure will create the column with a double qoutes ("ID","NM") hence the error occurred. Please find the updated code and check if the issue has resolved.

According to oracle=>

Oracle is case sensitive in column and table names. It just converts everything to upper case by default. But if you use names in double quotes, you tell Oracle to create the column in the exact spelling you provided (lower case in the CREATE statement).

## Code:

```
create or replace procedure table_creation(table_name in varchar2,col1 varchar2,col2 varchar2)
is
l_stat varchar2(3000);
v_stat varchar2(1000);
a varchar2(10):='1';
b varchar2(10):='Dummy';
begin
l_stat:='create table '||table_name||' ('||col1||' varchar2(10),'||col2||' varchar2(10))';
execute immediate l_stat;
execute immediate 'insert into '||table_name||'('||col1||','||col2||') values   (:x,:y)' using a,b;
end;
/
```

Note: I have not touched any other logic of the code. Please try and let us know the result.

Only change is

## From :

```
 l_stat:='create table '||table_name||' ("'||col1||'" varchar2(10),"'||col2||'" varchar2(10))';
```

## to :

```
 l_stat:='create table '||table_name||' ('||col1||' varchar2(10),'||col2||' varchar2(10))';
```

Comment: @Nickynick please remember that it is not advice able to use the create statement inside a plsql block. There are many instances where using create statements would instigate a lot of issues. Try checking out in web to understand the same. Thank you.